# Angular 2 : routing without changing URL

Tags: angular

How can i route in an Angular 2 app without changing the URL? (this is because the app is located under one of several tabs on a page of a Django app, where it's suitable to leave the URL unchanged.)

currently i have something like this inside `app.component.ts`

```
@RouteConfig([
  {
    path: '/home',
    name: 'Home',
    component: HomeComponent,
    useAsDefault: true
  },
  {
    path: '/user/:id',
    name: 'UserDetail',
    component: UserDetailComponent
  }
])
```

and inside say `HomeComponent`, navigation to a user page uses the following

```
this._router.navigate(['UserDetail', {id: id}]);
```

then the url will look like `http://localhost:8000/django_url/user/123`

is it possible to have the url unchanged when i navigate within the Angular 2 app? so the url will stay `http://localhost:8000/django_url` when a user is on page `user/123` ?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, I am facing the same problem. Did you found a solution for your problem? I am using Angular2 RC4

Comment: Is this a best practice, an anti-pattern, or something in between? What do the angular devs have to say on this?

Answer (score 101):

**Update**

```ts
router.navigateByUrl("/team/33/user/11", { skipLocationChange: true });
```

```ts
<a [routerLink]="..." skipLocationChange>click me</a>
```

**Update**

There is a PR to support this directly https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/9608

Related issues

- https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9579
- https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9949

**Original**

You can implement a custom `PlatformLocation` similar to [BrowserPlatformLocation](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/bb8976608db93b9ff90a71187608a4390cbd7a07/modules/%40angular/common/src/location/platform_location.ts) but instead of calling ot `history.pushState()`, `history.replaceState()`, `history.back()`, and `history.forward()` maintain the changes in a local array.

You can then make Angular use your custom implementation by providing it like

```ts
bootstrap(AppComponent, 
    [provide(PlatformLocation, {useClass: MyPlatformLocation})]);
```

Comment: currently i don't call `history.pushState()`, `history.replaceState()` or others. can you point me to some resource regarding `pushState` and `PlatformLocation`? thanks!

Comment: You don't but the router does through `PlatformLocation`. This is what updates the URL. If you provide a custom implementation for `PlatformLocation` you can prevent this. I haven't thought a lot about this yet. Maybe you can just provide an implementation that does nothing and there is no need to maintain any state. Most of this is just to make the back/forward buttons work. If you don't reflect the navigation in the URL this might not make sense anyway.

Comment: could you give an example (or point me to some resources) of how to implement this custom `PlatformLocation` and where to place it? thanks again!

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add the URL. I updated my answer. When you have your custom implementation you provide it by `bootstrap(AppComponent, [provide(PlatformLocation, {useClass: MyPlatformLocation})])`

Answer (score 21):

Finally its working in Angular2 final release. You need to pass { skipLocationChange: true } while navigating to the path i.e.

```
 this.router.navigateByUrl('path', { skipLocationChange: true });
```

Comment: How to do the { skipLocationChange: true } from anchor tag?

Comment: Is there anyway to do this globally so every single call to `navigate` doesn't need these parameters passed in?

Comment: works for me! I'm using this for a not found page and rather than using 'history.go(-2);' I prefer not changing the wrong url. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

`this.router.navigateByUrl('path', { skipLocationChange: true });`
also worked for me.

In `Routes` array I also added my path to load a component as below:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [    
   { path: 'Account/MySchool', component: MySchoolComponent }
];
```

And in the file from there i need to replace the component, initialize `router` object like below and call at required place

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

constructor(private router: Router) {    }


onSubmit() {        
    this._requestService.postPageOneData("Account/SavePageOneData", this.userProfile)
        .subscribe((response) => {
            if(response.status == 'success'){
                   this.router.navigateByUrl('Account/PageTwoSelection', { skipLocationChange: true });
              }
        }, this.handleErrorSubscribed );
    }
```