# How to skip a page in browser history when navigating back?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have an Angular 2 app with the Router. Let's say the user is on a page A in the app, he then navigates to a page B and then to a page C. At this moment when he clicks the Back button on the browser I want him to get back to the page A (by skipping B). How can I achieve it?

Comment: This answer might be helpfull http://stackoverflow.com/a/37055297/3283209

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When navigating from B to C one has to set { replaceUrl: true }:

```
this.router.navigate(["/c"], { replaceUrl: true });
```

This replaces the page B by C in the browser history.

Answer (score 1):

Quick and easy solution is

Use navigation in your typescript instead of html file .

And specify the parameter

```
{ skipLocationChange: true }
```

Proper solution is to write your own navigation strategy and specify in app.modules.ts