# Correct Routing in a tabbed modal in Angular

Tags: angular, routes, modal-dialog

I created a modal using MatDialog. This Modal opens a component that has a tabbed page inside.

```
this.dialog.open(AuthComponent, dialogConfig);
```

I used the mat-tab-nav-bar to open the two tabbed components for Login and Register.

```
<nav mat-tab-nav-bar mat-align-tabs="center">
        <a mat-tab-link
           *ngFor="let link of navLinks"
           [routerLink]="link.path"
           routerLinkActive #rla="routerLinkActive"
           [active]="rla.isActive">
          {{link.label}}
        </a>
      </nav>

      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

To open the modal works fine, but the login component is not loaded when i open the modal. I first have to click on the link.

[image: When i open the modal]

"Click on Login"

[image: locin clicked]

My routing looks pretty  straight forward:

```
{ path: 'signup', component: SignupComponent},

{ path: 'login',  component: LoginComponent},
```

Do you have any thoughts?
Jakob

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
export class AuthComponent implements OnInit {    

  constructor(private router: Router) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.router.navigate(['signup'])        
  }
}
```

Comment: So simple! Thank you!

Comment: I have encountered another problem here: If i use routing in a mat-tab-nav-bar like this i have a problem with the back button in the browser. If i click on back, the modal closes but i am still at /login or /signup

Comment: try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41874826/how-to-skip-a-page-in-browser-history-when-navigating-back