# Change Id to Name in Angular 2 Route

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing

Well, I did some research before asking this question. I thought this is very straight forward as this common scenario.

This is my anchor tag.

```
  <a [routerLink]="['./product', 1]">Vitamins</a>
```

When use click on that I am getting data by passing the Id to Web API. After getting data, the Url shows up as http://localhost:4200/product/1.

In my route, I configured this as

```
{ path: 'product/:id', component: ProductComponent },
```

I would like to modify this URL as http://localhost:4200/vitamins which makes more sense. How can I do this ?

The closest I found is this but this is not what I am looking for

[Angular 2 : routing without changing URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37054731/angular-2-routing-without-changing-url)

Comment: as long as the name is unique, you can use the name as id.

Comment: @RobinDijkhof Name is not unquie. Even thoug it is unique, I think I will get it as http://localhost:4200/product/Vitamins. but I dont want product in between. Thanks

Comment: or you can do `{ path: 'product/:productName/:id', component: ProductComponent }`

Comment: from `http://localhost:4200/vitamins` how will the router know that you want to load `ProductComponent` to outlet? You can use `product/:productName` by mapping names to ids.

Comment: you can change your path to `{ path: 'vitamins', component: ProductComponent }`
`<a routerLink="'./vitamins'">Vitamins</a>`
notice the removed brackets otherwise you get an `IllegalNumberException` in the server side

Comment: I dont think that this is a good idea, because you have to put route for each product.

Comment: @YordanNikolov Agree with you that giving path is not a good idea. as mentioned by Haythem. I tired your product/:productName/:id still it is giving the id in the url like http://localhost:4200/product/Vitamins/1

Comment: What's the problem to have and an ID in the URL. I think that until you have the name of the product, which is better for the SEO, it doesnt make sanse that you have and the ID. You may structure the URL how you want ... `/product/productName-productId` .... it's up to you

Comment: @YordanNikolov I dont want user to see the Id's in URL. I want the URL to be easy to type

Comment: I dont think that there's a easy way to do that. I don't believe that you have products with unique names, if I'm wrong, you can do it only with name in the URL

Answer (score 1):

Try using Location object.

```
import { Location } from '@angular/common';

constructor(public location: Location) {}
```

And when you want to update the window URL without redirecting or navigating with router object, put this:

```
this.location.go('vitamins');
```

This should write 'vitamins' after your base url.

Comment: Not sure whether this is a good way to do it or not. I observed that the Url is first showing as http://localhost:4200/product/1 and then changing to  http://localhost:4200/vitamins. User can see that blinking

Comment: And the other thing I observed is User cannot type Website.com/Vitamins

Comment: You could try to use this in your ngOnInit method. Otherwise, when do you have to switch the url?

-- Edit
Then you should implement a new route with Vitamins

Answer (score 0):

I probably would just link to `<a [routerLink]="'/product'">Vitamins</a>`.
Make it optional and handle this case in your component or service (if no `id` is passed, set it to `1`)

In other cases you probably want the url to look like `http://myexample.com/vitamins/2` otherwise a direct link wouldn't be possible (or how would you pass the params otherwise?) for example if you wan't to bookmark the url or make a hard reload.

A hacky way would be to use `location.go('/vitamins');` ([Location Docs](https://angular.io/api/common/Location)) which will change the url in your address bar, but won't trigger any route changes of the `angular router`.
I call it hacky, because it can have sideeffects such as the bookmarking / reload problem if you're on a specific route (of course you could solve this in another way, lets say temporarily saving the current route param in `localStorage`).

Hope i could help.