# Angular 2: Routing without changing URL globally

Tags: angular, routes

This [thread on angular routing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37054731/angular-2-routing-without-changing-url) shows how to route without changing the URL displayed in the browser by using the `skipLocationChange` option,

```
 router.navigateByUrl("/team/33/user/11", { skipLocationChange: true });
```

We have 30 or so routes and would like to implement this globally so as not to have to change it in 30 places in the code.  Is there any way to achieve this?