# lazy loading without change url in angular5

Tags: angular, angular5

I want load module without change url in angular 5.
Is it possible to load module with lazy loading on click without change a url and also do not change route in angular5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can using

```
{ skipLocationChange: true }
```

while you navigation to route. It will navigates without pushing a new state into history.

Refer :

- [Angular 2 : routing without changing URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37054731/angular-2-routing-without-changing-url)
- https://angular.io/api/router/NavigationExtras

Comment: yes, exsetly like that but content which is shown 
that will be lazy loded
is it possible?