# Angular 2-7: What's the best approach of hiding/showing components on same URL?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7, angular-routing, angular7-router

> Due to some platform restrictions, there I can't use Routing - different urls to navigate to different components.
>
> In other words, there is only http://localhost.com/default
>
> NO http://localhost.com/user
>
> NO http://localhost.com/items
>
> I manage to put all the child components in the AppComponent as a parent and use variables to indicate which child component to hide and show by ui actions in order to manipulate the layout.

```
<app-user-panel
  [hidden]="!showUser"
  (closed)="onUserPanelClosed($event)"
></app-user-panel>

<app-items-panel
  [hidden]="!showItems"
  (closed)="onItemsPanelClosed($event)"
></app-items-panel>
```

> As there are massive components are put together, the code in ts file is messy.
>
> I am wondering if there is any better approach of NOT using booleans and ngIf to show or hide child components?
>
> RESOLUTION 1: Does Routing have an advanced feature to navigate to different components on same url?
>
> RESULUTION 2: Use Routing params?

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37054731/angular-2-routing-without-changing-url

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> RESOLUTION 1: Does Routing have an advanced feature to navigate to
>   different components on same url?

Yes you can use hash location strategy instead. This way your pages are routed by only angular.

Example: http://localhost.com/#/user
Your server will not try to return a page for user, instead angular will evaluate it and render your user screen.

The only thing you need to do is initing useHash with true

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {useHash: true})],
  exports: [ RouterModule ]
})
```

This would be a better solution then looking into a cleaner way to hide and show components in one page.